# How to bind List<DisplayedInfo> to datagridview with DataGridViewAutoFilter library?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I need to add filter function to my DataGridView. I try to use DataGridViewAutoFilter library today, but it's not working for my Winform application if I use desinger to change my column type to `DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn` as the document told me. After I looked into the sample of DataGridViewAutoFilter sample, I think there is some problem in data source binding.

I bind my data source as this:

[image]

The DisplayedInfo is the metedata object I am using to store the information.

My binding code is

```
Ilist<DisplayedInfo> infos = new List<DisplayedInfo>();
infos = GetAllInfosFromServer();
displayedInfoBindingSource = infos;
```

I think I can't use type `List` here as my data source cause the document of DataGridViewAutoFilter indicate that `BindingSource` component must be bound to an `IBindingListView`.

The sample project of DataGridViewAutoFilter bind data source like this:

[image]

About the `newDataSet`, it seems like a custom component, I don't quite get how it works. It looks like this on designer:

[image]

You can get sample projects here: [sample download url](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23459). So how should I modify my code to make it work like the sample.

I tried to convert my `List` to a `IBindingListView` implement, such as `Equin.ApplicationFramework.BingdingListView`, but it's still not working.

Help please!

Here is my convert code:

```
public class AdvancedListHelper
{
    public static BindingListView<DisplayedInfo> ListToBindableList(IList<DisplayedInfo> infos)
    {
        if (infos == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        BindingListView<DisplayedInfo> advancedInfos = new BindingListView<DisplayedInfo>((List<DisplayedInfo>)infos);
           
        return advancedInfos;
    }

}
```

I found a problem about `DataGridViewAutoFilter`. You can not change `FilteringEnabled` to true in the designer. I don't know why but I add this code to my Winform:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in columns)
{
    if (col is DataGridViewAutoFilter.DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn)
    {
        var c = col as DataGridViewAutoFilter.DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn;
        var cell = c.HeaderCell;
        if (cell is DataGridViewAutoFilter.DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell)
        {
            var ce = cell as DataGridViewAutoFilter.DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell;
            ce.FilteringEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can make the Filter button visible. But when I click the button, I get a unhandled exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot set filter from string expression.

I think it's the `Equin.ApplicationFramework.BingdingListView` problem. So right now I really need a class to replace `Equin.ApplicationFramework.BingdingListView`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in one word `deferred execution`

Add `.ToList()` either inside `ListToBindableList`, or on its return value.

Comment: Like this?```displayedInfoBindingSource.DataSource = AdvancedListHelper.ListToBindableList(source).ToList<DisplayedInfo>();```.still not work...

Comment: @Xia, try just `.ToList()`

Comment: still no filter...I think data source must be a ```IBindingListView``` implement,and ```ToList()``` can't meet that requirement.